# ignite new MyApp results in "template not found"

Tags: react-native

Attemping my first use of [ignite to create a React-Native application using boilerplate](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite). After following the installation instructions...

```
$ node -v
v10.14.1
$ npm install -g ignite-cli
$ ignite new MyNewAppName
( Choosing `Bowser` when prompted )
```

Results in...

```
✔ using the Infinite Red boilerplate v3 (code name 'Bowser')
✔ added React Native 0.57.7 in 38.8s
an error occured while installing ignite-ir-boilerplate-bowser boilerplate.
Error: template not found /Users/tyler/Github/ReactNativeBowser/node_modules/ignite-ir-boilerplate-bowser/boilerplate/.gitignore
```

How fix?

Answer (score 1):

You've missed one vital instruction in the [installation checklist](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite#arrow_down-install). You have to [install Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install), before creating your app.